# Create new paragraph for every new State instead of updating my stateful component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When I click on the Create Sales Order Button I do a API call and print the Response as a Stateful Component. But instead of updating my Stateful Component  I want to create a new paragraph for every response I got so if the user presses the button 5x he has 5 paragraphs with the response.

How can I achieve this? I thought about pushing the response to an array but I'm not sure about that

```
function ContentFunction () {
  const [value, setValue] = useState()

  function sendText (data) {
    setValue(data)
  }

  async function handleClick (event) {
    switch (event.target.id) {
      case 'createSalesOrder':
      {
        const res = await axios.post('http://localhost:5000/', {
          buttonClicked: 'createSalesOrder'

        })

        sendText(res.data)
        break
      }

      default:
        console.log('click didnt work')
    }
  }

  return (
    <main>
      <div className='container'>
        <Form>
          <Form.Group>
            <Button variant='success' className='button' onClick={handleClick} id='createSalesOrder'>Create Sales Order</Button>
          </Form.Group>
        </Form>
  {/* Here I want to create a new Paragraph for every response instead of just updating this */}
        <p>{value}</p>
      </div>
    </main>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use value as array
Example code:

```
function ContentFunction () {
  const [value, setValue] = useState([]) //init with empty array

  function sendText (data) {
    setValue([...value, data]) //Push new data into array
  }

  async function handleClick (event) {
    switch (event.target.id) {
      case 'createSalesOrder':
      {
        const res = await axios.post('http://localhost:5000/', {
          buttonClicked: 'createSalesOrder'

        })

        sendText(res.data)
        break
      }

      default:
        console.log('click didnt work')
    }
  }

  return (
    <main>
      <div className='container'>
        <Form>
          <Form.Group>
            <Button variant='success' className='button' onClick={handleClick} id='createSalesOrder'>Create Sales Order</Button>
          </Form.Group>
        </Form>
  {/* Here I want to create a new Paragraph for every response instead of just updating this */}
        {value.map(item => <p key={value}>{value}</p>)} //render value array
      </div>
    </main>
  )
}
```

Comment: How can I add a linebreak to the paragraph?  The following does not work  {
        value.map(item =>
          <p key={value}>{value} <br /> </p>

        )
      }

Comment: NO, you should use CSS to style element. Example: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_list_group.asp

Comment: I just noticed a problem, it created multiples paragraphs but every paragraph contains the whole array, i just want the new item shown, how can I achieve this?

Comment: Can you upload your layout?

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need that function that is then calling your set state hook, you are along the right lines with the array idea, you can push to your array for each response and then map over the data returning a paragraph for each response.

Although generally when mapping over data in React you will want to create a component to render said data.

```
function ContentFunction () {
  const [values, setValues] = useState([])

  async function handleClick (event) {
    switch (event.target.id) {
      case 'createSalesOrder':
      {
        const res = await axios.post('http://localhost:5000/', {
          buttonClicked: 'createSalesOrder'

        })

        setValues([...values], res.data);
        break;
      }

      default:
        console.log('click didnt work')
    }
  }

  return (
    <main>
      <div className='container'>
        <Form>
          <Form.Group>
            <Button variant='success' className='button' onClick={handleClick} id='createSalesOrder'>Create Sales Order</Button>
          </Form.Group>
        </Form>
        {values.map(value => <p key={value}>{value}</p>)}
      </div>
    </main>
  )
}
```

Comment: This does not run, it throws the values is not defined

Comment: Try now Jango please